# UWP - Hide RichEditBox touch selection 'grippers'

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How can I programatically hide the touch selection helpers on a RichEditBox? From what I can tell, they don't appear in the visual tree.

They're referred to as grippers here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/guidelines-for-textselection

The same problem can be reproduced with an ordinary TextBox as well:

[image]

After pressing the button, I'm left with:

[image]

I want the gripper to be hidden when the button is clicked instead of staying active. Focus should never leave the TextBox.

Here's the relevant XAML/C#. Note that AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" on the button is required.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Change Text" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" />
<TextBox Name="TextBox" Text="123" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox.Text += "1";
}
```

Comment: Then do you want the cursor?

Comment: I'm ok with the grippers appearing in response to the user touching the control. However, I have other buttons in my app that modify the text of the RichEditBox. I want the grippers to disappear when another button is tapped that modifies the text of the RichEditBox.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT any suggestions?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you actually want. Click the button will let the `RichEditBox` lose focus, the gripper may not exist. Maybe a screenshot can help you detail this more clearly.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Added further details. I have AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" for buttons since I need focus to stay on the RichEditBox.